# sharepoint: conditional formula for calculated field

Tags: sharepoint, conditional-statements, formula, calculated-columns

i want to create a formula for change my value from EUR into USD.

```
FIELD1 (choice): EUR, USD
FIELD2 (number): amount in EUR or USD
```

Now, if USD is selected in FIELD1 following should happen: calaculate `FIELD2*0,71` otherwiese the result is FIELD2.

```
FIELD3 (calculated): =IF(FIELD1="USD", (FIELD2*0,71), FIELD2))
```

When I use this formula I get error message: The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.

Any idea? I´m using english version of WSS 3.0.

Thank you, 
fiuman007

Comment: what did you mean by FIELD2*0,71. If you multiply a value with zero, the output will be Zero.

Answer (score 1):

In your formular your using comma as both decimal point and seperator. You have to change one of these.

Which one depends on your regional settings.

If your regional setting are using comma as decimal point then semicolon is usually used as seperator.